# is there 3-D Mapping in QtLocation Map?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, openstreetmap, qtlocation

I work on a qml map project and use osm plugin for offline map displaying. Here is some code about it.

```
Plugin{
    id: mapPlugin
    name: 'osm'

    PluginParameter {
        name: 'osm.mapping.offline.directory'
        value: 'qrc:/offline_tiles/'
    }
}
Map{
    id: map1
    anchors.fill: parent
    zoomLevel: 15
    plugin:mapPlugin

    center {
        // The Qt Company in Oslo
        latitude: 59.9485
        longitude: 10.7686
    }
}
```

I have to display 3D glope map but i couldn't any doc/tutorial about it. Someone can help for that how can i do 3D map in QML Map. Can you help me pls.

Comment: No, There is not.

Comment: well, is there any different lib, qml component, tool for this?

Comment: the non-free General Magic SDK, the non-free Esri SDK, nothing else ready-made afaik.
Some integrated osgEarth into Qt, you may try to go down that road.

Comment: why you dont use js library to show 3d map in webveiw and something like this?